# Flag Activity New Task Working

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, flags, back-stack

Please tell me the Working of FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

I am on main Activity then, I go to Activity A with affinity com.task. Then i call again A Activity with using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. Then it create A Activity on new task. Then i again call A Activity then nothing happen. On new Intent method not call this time.

My Question is : Why on new intent method did not call?